# Subgit: translation process with many branch/tag definitions extremely slow

Tags: subgit

Our subversion history is ... complicated. Using simple rule like

```
branches = branches/*:refs/heads/*
```

simply doesn't work. What I'm trying instead is to use

```
branches = branches/branch1:refs/heads/branch1
branches = branches/branch2/it:refs/heads/branch2
branches = branches/branch3/is:refs/heads/branch3
branches = branches/branch4/complicated:refs/heads/branch4
```

for each individual branch and tag, altogether 6500 rules. There is no rule using the wildcard.

Subgit doesn't like that very much, it makes translation process very slow (like 1 svn revision per minute).

Is there a way to speed it up, using our explicit branch/tags configuration?

Comment: I can confirm, that removing all those rules makes import much much faster.

Comment: Discussion continues at https://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SGT-1100